# Watchdog message is not proper

Tags: log-messages

Used sqlquery to get the error log messages from watchdog table.
Getting message like,

1. 'Sending mail to: @to'.
2. '%type: !message in %function (line    %line of %file)'
   (which seems not relevant).

How can I get error log message similar as shown at SiteReports-->Recent Log Messages  view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is serialised and uses an array of named placeholders, so you'll need to use PHP to assemble the full message:

```
// Get data from the DB, each record stored in $row, then...
$message = $row->message;
$variables = unserialize($row->variables);

$full_message = strtr($message, $variables);
```